# Sharing a solution or project between 2 TFS server

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

Can a solution to be setup in a way that can work with two TFS servers?

Thanks.

Comment: Do they share the same source control?

Comment: A better question is *why* you would ever want to do this?

Comment: You can, if your Team Project is a Git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will allow you to map your source folder from different servers to the same local folder.

Comment: I see. I was thinking the same but since new to it ... couldn't comment on it. Thanks